# Is it possible to define NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription within a Framework?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have developed a Framework which at some point will try to request the device's location. As I understand it, every App which includes this Framework will have to add a `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to **its own Info.plist** in order to make location usage possible from within the Framework.

Is there a way to provide a `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` already **inside** the Framework so I don't have to rely on the App to define it?

Adding is to the Framework's Info.plist doesn't work. Modifying the App's Info.plist at runtime is also not possible.

Comment: All frameworks I have seen which use CoreLocation have the developer include the `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` field themselves as part of their documentation. I am afraid there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

The info.plist is present in your Apps Bundle, which is READ-ONLY. This makes it impossible to modify it at runtime.

This makes a lot of sense too because Apple doesn't want Apps to request *X* permissions when the app is in review and switch to *Y* once the app is live. 
Not letting *Frameworks* directly request permissions also makes sense. Because you want the app to be aware what permissions related to users sensitive data, a third party piece of code needs before you include it in your code.

All iOS frameworks include required permissions in a *readMe* file or in such a relevant document along with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as i know... You will have to explain that in order to use your framework, the developer must include the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` tag.